# Async data for singleton pattern

Tags: javascript, csv, asynchronous, singleton

I was asked to create a singleton that will have methods which it will operate on some data it holds. The data is loaded from a nearby CSV file, but I cannot find a way to do it in an asynchronous way.

This is a Vanilla JavaScript assignment.
I have this CSV file, which I want to load/ read only once, and then "hold" inside of my singleton. Since all of the singleton's methods regard this data, I don't think there is a reason to read it more than once, at the beginning.
Since reading (and parsing) it is a asynchronous work, and so are some expected methods, I can't find the right way/ place/ method to do it.
Searching the internet shows that if I choose to create a class, the constructor must NOT by asynchronous.
An IIFE pattern did not work for me as well...

I currently have no code, since nothing seems to work, unfortunately.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. All of the approaches are fine, so it is personal preference.

### 1. Static Method

```
class CsvHandler {
    static readFile(fileName) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
             const instance = new CsvHandler()
             // Process your csv file here
             resolve(instance);
        }
    }
}
const csvHandler = CsvHandler.readFile('fileName.txt')
```

### 2. Factory Method

```
class CsvHandler {}

class CsvFactory {
    readFile(fileName) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
             const instance = new CsvHandler()
             // Process your csv file here
             resolve(instance);
        }
    }
}

var csvFactory = new CsvFactory(),
    csvHandler = csvFactory.readFile('fileName.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to your class that builds an instance of the class with the required data having fetched the CSV file.an example is this:

```
class Importer{ 
private importerInstance: Importer
private constructor(private csvData){
...
}

// returns an instance of the importer
static async composeInstance(path to CSV){

... retrieve file content asynchronously
if(!this.importerInstance) {return new Importer(<result of async csv fetching>)} else {return this.importerInstance}
}
}
```

Let me know if it makes any sense. I could try to do a more elaborate example for you

Comment: I like your addition of the newer async flags, but this example is pretty confusing, especially for those who may be new to javascript, especially async programming. I think the OP would benefit from a bit more explanation.

Comment: thanks @PeterLaBanca. Your example covers pretty much what I had in mind in pure JS